# How To Make Json_encode PHP To An Text String Number

Tags: php, json, codeigniter-4

Hello Everyone I Want To Ask How To Make Output Using Json_Encode To An Text
Here's My Code

Model

```
function count_topup($ID)
{
    $this->db->select_sum("Jumlah");
    $this->db->from('topup');
    $this->db->where('id_user',$ID);
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
  $data['Count'] = $this->user_model->count_topup($ID);
```

View

```
<?php echo json_encode($Count);?>
```

it will give output [{"Jumlah":"150000"}]

How To Make Only showing 150000? Thanks For The Help

Comment: now try with my updated view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of `json_encode();`

**Controller:-**

```
$data['Count'] = $this->user_model->count_topup($ID);
$this->load->view('Your_view', $data);
```

**View:-**

```
   foreach ($Count as $c)
 {
   <?php echo $c['Jumlah'];?>
  }
```

**Note:-** For regarding how Array data is passed from controller to view is

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html

Comment: I Already Using This And Giving Error   ` Array to string conversion`